# Getting ProgrammingError at ... using Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I made some changes to my models.py file and now I return this error when I try to access my heroku app's `admin` page:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column testingland_mapcafes.cafe_image_url does not exist
LINE 1: ...s"."venue_type", "testingland_mapcafes"."source", "testingla...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 622, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 236, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1828, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1202, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/testingland/mapcafes/
Exception Value: column testingland_mapcafes.cafe_image_url does not exist
LINE 1: ...s"."venue_type", "testingland_mapcafes"."source", "testingla...
```

I have tried running `heroku run python3 manage.py migrate` and get `No migrations to apply.`

I deleted my `migrations` cache folder and also manually dropped a column from my Heroku postgres CLI to try and fix things but fear I only made it worse.

Here is the relevant `models.py`

```
class mapCafes(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
```

When I manually check the table through the Heroku DATABASE CLi the `cafe_image_url` column is not there - suggesting the migration isn't occurring correctly.

FWIW - everything works correctly on my local server.

Comment: Did you make migrations before applying them?

Comment: Yes - but I also deleted the contents of the ``migrations`` folder to try and fix the error.

Comment: Is the database already populated? If not, you can simply run `manage.py migrate`, to revert all the migrations you just deleted, then run `manage.py makemigrations`, and then `manage.py migrate` to regenerate the database schema.

Comment: If there is already data in the database, I'd try to get the migrations directory you just deleted back. And then run `manage.py make migrations` and try to migrate again.

Comment: I run ``python3 manage.py migrate`` and it says there are ``no migrations to apply`` - I try ``python3 manage.py makemigrations`` and get ``no changes detected``. If I just run ``manage.py [...]`` without ``python(3)`` I get ``zsh: command not found: manage.py``

Comment: Can you post the content of the migration file(s) that create or alter `mapCafes`?

Comment: Thanks for the response I  could not find the migration files at all! tried to reset the db using ``heroku pg:reset`` and have created new problems :(

Comment: "I deleted my `migrations` cache folder"—your `migrations/` folder is _not_ a cache! It is a critical part of your source code.

Comment: Damn. Any advice how to rectify?